# Remove trust from built app package file once added to windows trusted app

Tags: windows, blocking, digital-signature, trusted-root-certificates

I created package of an app I developed. When running the built app it was blocked by windows. So I checked the Unblock from the properties as show in the below image.

[image]

But Now I want to remove it from the unblocked application from the windows. to test if my digital code signing works. I cannot find any option to uncheck the Unblock  option.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

What you doing is a one-way street. You would probably need to manually edit the registry to block the program again. There is just no purpose to unblocking and then blocking again. Either the program is safe, or it isn't! Once it is determined to be safe, that's what the registry records.

Comment: @Ramhound5 Where do I accuse anyone of anything? Am I not permitted to use my talents for preemptively reading emotions online? You are the one doing the accusing. I hadn't even noticed anyone downvoted anything. I'm just gonna go.

Comment: I simply took your comment the wrong way. It’s due to far to many problem in the past doing what I thought you had done.

Comment: @Brian, I am not offended. I guess you looking from the point of view that once we know the app is safe we do not need to block it again. But as I mentioned, I developed an application and I have to create the application package and generate the exe file. Now to test run it, I unblocked it. But As you know if you want to distribute your app or to distribute your code it has to be digitally signed. That is why I wanted to block the app again so that I can check that a third party or other systems will not block the application as untrusted app. so let me know how to do that in reg edits.

Comment: I was saying that it doesn't make sense usually for Windows to permit reversing the process, because this situation is unusual. Normally, it would not be necessary for a normal user to do so. So maybe there is a developer setting you can tweak. Sorry, I don't develop on WIN any longer, not since XP.